# ValueError: convolve2d inputs must be both 2D arrays

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm working on a program that takes in a video, splits the video into a sequence of images, applies a cleaning filter to the images (denoise/deblur/etc.), then puts it back together into a video.

I wanted to use Scikit Image's "Unsupervised_wiener" restoration on the images to de-blur them, but I haven't been able to get it and I don't understand the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.wiener).

This is what I have, copied from the documentation:

```
frame = color.rgb2gray
frame = convolve2d(frame, psf, 'same')
frame += 0.1 * frame.std() * np.random.standard_normal(frame.shape)
fixed = skimage.restoration.unsupervised_wiener(frame, psf)
```

Where "frame" is a frame from the input, which I captured with OpenCV2:

```
ret, frame = vid.read()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 1025, in convolve2d
ValueError: convolve2d inputs must both be 2D arrays
```

How do I convert the input frames into a 2D array so that Scikit Image can process them?

Any help would be great, or if there's a better method I can use, I'm open to that as well. Thanks!

Edit: pst shape is: (5,5), frame shape is: (1080, 1920, 3)

Comment: What are `frame.shape` and `psf.shape`?

Comment: psf is (5,5) and frame is (1080, 1920, 3)

The source video is a 1920x1080 video.

Comment: Got it. That means your frame is still RGB, not grayscale (for a grayscale 1080p image the shape should be (1080, 1920)). Can you try `frame = skimage.color.rgb2gray(frame)` before the convolution? The OP (`frame = color.rgb2gray`) suggests you might be doing this step incorrectly.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the color image while running the filter? It's important to keep the output in color for this project. (Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.)

Comment: Ah, sure. You can do that by convolving each of the channels separately. I'm not sure what the best way to do that in `scipy` is, but _a_ way to do it would be just using a for loop:
`for i in range(frame.shape[-1]):
        frame[:,:,i] = convolve2d(frame[:,:,i], pcf, mode="same")`
(Note that you might get broken results if your kernel is `float`s but your image isn't; I needed to do `frame = frame.astype(np.float32)` after loading it to convolve an RGB image without artifacts).

Comment: Okay great! Now it's saying it can't broadcast from (5,5) into (5,5,3). How can I pass each of these channels in individually and then put them back into their original format?

Comment: The for loop method described in the comment above should do exactly that. Here's a gist showing how it can fit into a full program: https://gist.github.com/madebyollin/4ad0964292449c4e21368003cf9401f7

Comment: I did implement the for loop as you wrote it in your comment, I added a comment on the snippet that shows what my implementation looks like.

Comment: Oh, wait. Is the `ValueError` is getting thrown from the `unsupervised_wiener` line, not the `convolve2d` line? I think that function also takes a 2D input (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.unsupervised_wiener) so you'll need to use a similar for loop there as well.

Comment: That's correct, but even using the lines you suggested, it's still throwing an error.

Thanks for the help again, you're a champ.

Comment: Ah, oops, that's because the `unsupervised_wiener` function returns two values. I think you only want the first one (see the new comment on the gist)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your diligence and patience. Can you please add your snippet as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input frames are RGB, but `convolve2d` and `unsupervised_wiener` expect 2D (grayscale) arrays.

You can resolve this by applying the operators to each channel individually.

Here is a fixed version of the original code that does per-channel operations:

```
# convolve each channel with the kernel
for i in range(frame.shape[-1]):
    frame[:,:,i] = convolve2d(frame[:,:,i], psf, mode="same")

# add gaussian noise
frame += 0.1 * frame.std() * np.random.standard_normal(frame.shape)

# wiener deconvolution
fixed = np.zeros(frame.shape)
for i in range(frame.shape[-1]):
    fixed[:,:,i], _ = restoration.unsupervised_wiener(frame[:,:,i], psf)
```

The result is stored in `fixed`, and the input and output are assumed to be numpy float arrays with values in the range [0,1].